# cfset getdata - where does info get defined?

Tags: coldfusion, adobe, coldfusion-9, cfml

```
<cfset GetData = integrationcomponent.easySocket(reference,form.PhoneNum,form.Amount,form.networkType)>
```

where would integrationcomponent.easySocket be defined ?

Comment: Are you asking where you should set the object or where the object might be set in your code base? It's impossible to know where it's defined with the limited info you have provided.

Comment: i would like to know where it is set, and what exactly its pointing to ? i am assuming its point to some url ?

Answer (score 1):

integrationcomponent would have to be defined on the page, or in the function, you are calling the method since it is not scoped to be anywhere else.

Comment: *would have to be defined ...* Very likely, but it is not absolutely certain.  Technically, the variables scope could be modified by something outside the script itself. For example by OnRequest, a custom tag, etcetera...

Comment: is it possible to add some code in the page to reveal the location of where integrationcomponent.easySocket maybe pointing to ? or even some code  that i may execute the page normally as a web user and log all the data and requests to a file for anlysis ?

Comment: using something like CFDUMP ?